# Merge two Google Analytics properties (on two different subdomains)

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have currently two domains for my service www.domain.com and app.domain.com. Our website is on www, our application is on app.
Currently, we also have two Google Analytics properties (one for website and the second for app).

This configuration was not really studied and we are now doubting about it. What do you think of it ? For conversion tracking, it's currently impossible to study funnels etc (the users comes to the website, open the app, uses the service and pay on the website) thus we are thinking of merging the properties.

Also, if this configuration is not convenient, how is it possible to merge those properties ?
And then, how to manage the differences between app and website ? Only using views ?

Comment: You can't merge data of different Accounts/Properties. You can also use multiple property ids on your sites. 
One for every subdomain and another wich tracks both.